# Python Flask app unable to parse XML request data

Tags: python, xml, flask

I wrote a simple flask app to parse XML requests and send a response. But when i try to parse the XML request, I get "unbound method get_data() must be called with Request instance as first argument (got nothing instead)".

I've tried variations of get_data with arguments according to https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.get_data' . I've also looked at a similar issue in SO, but that didn't help me.

```py
from flask import Flask, Response, Request
import xmltodict
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello"

@app.route("/testapp", methods = ['POST'], strict_slashes=False)

def parseRequest():
    content = xmltodict.parse(Request.get_data)
    print content

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I send request using curl

```
curl -i -X POST "http://x.x.x.x:5000/testapp" -H "accept: application/xml" -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data @test.xml
```

This is the content of the XML file.

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
...
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <com:qRequest xmlns:com=http://masked1          
                xmlns:xcom=http://masked2  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <com:Query xsi:type="xcom:DynamicNamedQuery">
                <xcom:Identifier>getDetails</xcom:Identifier>
                <xcom:Parameters>
                    <paramvalue>ABCDE</paramvalue>
                </xcom:Parameters>
            </com:Query>
        </com:qRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is the error I get - "TypeError: unbound method get_data() must be called with Request instance as first argument (got nothing instead)" . I've tried decoding it as utf8 as well, but I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: it should be rather `request.get_data()` - with lower `r` and `()` at the end.

Comment: `Request` is class name. And `requests` is instance of class `Request` which has all inforamtion from client.

Answer (score 2):

Working code. Just wrong uses of classes in your case

```py
import xmltodict
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello"

@app.route("/testapp", methods = ['POST', 'GET'], strict_slashes=False)
def parseRequest():
    content = xmltodict.parse(request.get_data())
    print (content)
    return content


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```